# The address of character type variable

Tags: c++, char, character, memory-address

Here is just a test prototype :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int a=10;
   char b='H';
   string c="Hamza";

   cout<<"The value of a is : "<<a<<endl;
   cout<<"The value of b is : "<<b<<endl;
   cout<<"The value of c is : "<<c<<endl<<endl;

   cout<<"address of a : "<<&a<<endl;
   cout<<"address of b : "<<&b<<endl;
   cout<<"address of c : "<<&c<<endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Why the address of variable 'b', which is of character type, not printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<<` operator in your code is overloaded in C++ 11. It doesn't conflict with any of other types like `int` or `string`, but it takes pointer to `char` which if used can produce undesired results.

You can do it like:-

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&b)
```

Answer (score 11):

There is an overload for `<<` which takes a pointer to `char` and interprets it as a terminated C-style string. Using this for the address of any other `char` will go horribly wrong.

Instead, convert to a typeless pointer so that `<<` doesn't get too clever:

```
cout << static_cast<void*>(&b)
```

Comment: thanks but can anyone give me a link which explains this "overload" for << and typeless pointers and other stuff. And when do I need to use typeless static pointers .. ??

Comment: @HamzaUmar: There are references for this overload [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/). C++11 27.7.3.6.4 is the definitive reference. Your introductory book should describe the uses of `void*`.

Answer (score 3):

Expression &b has type char *. When operator << used fo an object of type char * it considers it as a string and outputs it as a string. To output the address you should write

```
( void * ) &b
```

or

```
reinterpret_cast<void *>( &b )
```